# Issue exporting iOS App (Added Binary not using correct provision profile)

Tags: ios, xcode, export

I have recently added the Card IO sdk to my iOS and have successfully tested my integration with it. When I go to export my project for the app store, I get the screen below which shows my project and the correct provisioning profile and the added card io library with no provisioning profile.

[image: xcode error]

When I try to continue I get the message below.

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unchecking "Include app symbols for your application to receive symbolicated crash logs from Apple" seems to fix it.